# Rails + Ember: Nested models incorrect format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ember.js, rails-api

I have a Rails API and I am trying to pull in records in Ember and while its working, my nested model is not.  I have an `Employee` that `belongs_to` a `Location` and have created a serializer like so:

```
class API::EmployeeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :phone, :email, :manager, :terminated, :location
  belongs_to :location
end
```

which outputs:

```
{"employee":
    {"id":19,"name":"John Abreu","phone":"","email":"","manager":false,"terminated":false,"location":
        {"name":"Peabody","id":2}
    }
}
```

and my ember app pulls this in through:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('employee')
    }
});
```

but I hit my error when I encounter the `location` portion of the hash.  I get the following:

```
> Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected the data for the location
> relationship on a <employee:19> to be in a JSON API format and include
> an `id` and `type` property but it found {name: Peabody, id: 2}.
> Please check your serializer and make sure it is serializing the
> relationship payload into a JSON API format.
```

How can I correct this?  I already have a `LocationSerializer` that has:

```
class LocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :phone, :address, :name
end
```

Comment: Try changing `:location` to `:location_id` in the attributes

Comment: No luck, it correctly includes the `:location_id` but still includes the `location` hash which is where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was add a `type` attribute to the location hash.  According to [JSONAPI.org](http://jsonapi.org/format/) type should be in the following format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      // ... this article's attributes
    },
    "relationships": {
      // ... this article's relationships
    }
  }
}
```

so I modified my `LocationSerializer` to the following:

```
class LocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :phone, :address, :name, :type

  def type
    return "location"
  end
end
```